# TNS Listener error

Tags: sql, windows, database, oracle

I've installed Oracle 11g and now I'm getting the following error when I try to connect with PL-SQL Developer

> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the
>   connect identifier specified

How do I check what 'identifier' is specified?

There are two TNS listeners in my services now but only the 11g can start because the 9i directory does not exist anymore.

Anyone know a solution?

My **tnsnames.ora**

> ORCL =   (DESCRIPTION =
>       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = XXX_L07082.xxx-batt.local)(PORT =
>   1521))
>       (CONNECT_DATA =
>         (SERVER = DEDICATED)
>         (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
>       )   )

My **listner.ora**

> LISTENER =   (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
>       (DESCRIPTION =
>         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
>         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = XXX_L07082.xxx-batt.local)(PORT = 1521))
>       )   )

**sqlnet.ora**

> SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
>
> NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES,
>   EZCONNECT)

**TNSPING ORCL**

> Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION =
>   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =
>   XXX_L070
>   82.xxx-batt.local)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)
>   (SERVICE_N AME = orcl))) OK (40 msec)

Comment: What does `ping XXX_L07082.xxx-batt.local` say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have multiple Oracle clients installed at the same time?

Unfortunately, if you install multiple versions of the Oracle client, they sometimes (maybe often?) don't work well together. What is probably happening is that some of the paths are getting mixed between the two versions of the Oracle client. I would remove the older one.

What happens if you type in: tnsping [name]

Maybe tnsping will give you some more useful information.

In Windows, I have fixed these sorts of problems before by editing the PATH environment variable, and removing all references to the old Oracle client. You can edit the PATH environment variable by going to Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings (Vista and 7 only) -> Advanced (tab) -> Environment Variables... I usually copy out the path and edit it in notepad, then copy the edited path back in.

If this doesn't work and the directory structure for the old client exists, then I would copy the tnsnames.ora into the Network/Admin directory of the old client to see if that works.

Comment: problem solved. not exactly how you said but the other way around. i copied the tnsnames.ora from the old oracle to the new one thanks. i should have done that in the start  doh!