# unable to start TNSListener service for Oracle 12

Tags: oracle

I can't start up the TNSListener Service.
The problem is(Google Translate):

> The service on the local computer stops after startup. Some services
>   will automatically stop when not used by other services or programs

I searched on the internet.

> 1. Changing listener.ora and tnsnames.ora HOST parameter is not helping.
> 2. lsnrctl status says: Unable to OpenSCManager: err=5. TNS-12560 and TNS-00350.
> 3. Regedit is not helping.

When I installed Oracle 12c the first time, it's working, but after restarted, the listener can't be started.

I'm using win10x64.

By the way, sql plus can connect to the database, but PL/SQL Developer can't.

Thank you.

Comment: Can SQL Plus connect when you connect as `sqlplus /@localhost/service_name AS sysdba` (or whatever user you would normally connect as)?

Comment: Try the solution from this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592807/tns-listener-error

Comment: Have you examined a listener log file ? Run the command `lsnrctl stat` this will print a location of the log file on the disk, and then check last errors in the log.